# MATLAB vector operation. How to get previous element in vector to compute next element?

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

I have a vector A, say

```
A = [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want to perform an operation on this vector to get the next element. For example, say

```
A(i) = A(i - 1) * 5  [for i >= 2]
```

This can be easily achieved via a loop. But I want to achieve it by using vector operation. So far I have tried

```
A = [1, 0, 0, 0]
A(2:4) = A(1:3) * 5
```

But the content in A after this operation is coming as

```
A = [1 5 0 0]
```

The targeted answer should be

```
A = [1 5 25 125]
```

Please, mention the necessary changes to be made to achieve the target.

[Note: Please do not simply consider the above example as the elements which are power of 5 but consider A(i) = A(i - 1) * 5.]

Comment: This operation inherently *depends* on evaluating each value in turn. Loops are not necessarily slow or bad, why are you trying to avoid one for a sequential operation which lends itself to a loop so well?

Comment: Because vector operation is one-liner and needs less code than a loop. Just wanted to know if there any way to do so. It would enhance my knowledge also. [I am not aginst the loop ... :)]

Answer (score 1):

how about that:

```
A(1)*5.^[0:numel(A)-1]
```

Comment: Ok.. It may produce the equivalent result. But the target to access the previous element to get next has been ignored. Like if I say say A(1) = cos(0)  and A(i) = cos(A(i - 1)) ..Then it would not be possible through this.

Comment: not sure I understood your example so `A(2)=cos(A1)=cos(cos(0)) ?`